# Integrate option to save as PPT in NavigationToolbar2Tk in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

NavigationToolbar2Tk has options to save as png, pdf, jpeg, etc,. I have a created a function to save a chart as PPT in my tkinter window. I would like to add the save as PPT option in NavigationToolbar2Tk. Can any one please tell me how to achieve this?

**Code I use for saving as PPT:**

```
def saveasPPT(self):
    image_stream = BytesIO()
    self.fig.savefig(image_stream)
    prs = Presentation()
    # Use the output from analyze_ppt to understand which layouts and placeholders
    # to use
    # Create a title slide first
    title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
    title = slide.shapes.title
    title.text = 'By ' + self.labels[self.buttonIDcopy].cget('text')
    pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(image_stream, Inches(1), Inches(1), width=Inches(9), height=Inches(6))
    pptFilename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                               filetypes=(("powerpoint files", "*.pptx"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    if (pptFilename!=''):
        prs.save(pptFilename+'.pptx')
```

Comment: You can create a class inheriting from `NavigationToolbar2Tk`, copy the code for the `save_figure()` method and edit it to check for the file extension to apply your `saveasPPT()` method when required.

Comment: Where can I find the `save_figure()` method? I couldn't find it in `backend_bases`. I only see `raise NotImplementedError` there

Comment: `<python_lib_folder>/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py`